# How to install react-phone-number-input with Yarn?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I want to install the [`react-phone-number-input`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input) package into my Reactjs project. I am using Yarn as my package manager.

So I did the following command

```
yarn add react-phone-number-input
```

and received the following error.

> ./node_modules/dnd-core/lib/HandlerRegistry.js
>   Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/node_modules/dnd-core/lib/HandlerRegistry.js'

What am I doing wrong? How can I use Yarn to install react-phone-number-input?

Edit

Based on an answer, I tried the following

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn autoclean --init # creates .yarnclean file
yarn autoclean --force
yarn install
yarn add react-phone-number-input
```

and got the following error.

> TypeError: _dndCore.DragDropManager is not a constructor

Comment: update ALL your dependencies and retry

Comment: you could also try upgrading yarn itself (through npm) , but before you do that, use yarn to remove the package and then run *yarn add* with **--peer** , that may help also

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove node_modules, clean up yarn, install again.

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn cleanup
yarn install
yarn add react-phone-number-input
```

Comment: I don't see a `yarn cleanup` command. Did you mean `yarn autoclean`?